# Thymeleaf dynamic created form input value

Tags: forms, thymeleaf, input-field

I've got form wherefields are generated dynamically, but also I want to put into them values - it's kind a form where user can edit and accept before parsed text. So I'm doing

```
th:value="${event.value.eventDescription}"
```

and I got only string representing object like

```
com.myPackage.model.ConferenceEvent@4a78868b
```

instead of real description which is inside this object.

Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/approveEvents}" th:object="${conferenceTimetable}" method="post">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Key</label></td>
            <td><label>EventDate</label></td>
            <td><label>EventDescription</label></td>
        </tr>

        <tr th:each="event: *{conferenceTimetableMap}">
            <td><span th:utext="${event.key}">Description</span></td>
            <td><span th:utext="${event.value.eventDate}">Description</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{conferenceTimetableMap[__${event.key}__]}" th:value="${event.value.eventDescription}"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th:field` writes the `name`, `value` and `id` of the input it's on.  So `*{conferenceTimetableMap[__${event.key}__]}` is the expressions that evaluates to `com.myPackage.model.ConferenceEvent@4a78868b` and not `${event.value.eventDescription}` (which is never used).

Instead, you should write the complete path to the variable you are submitting in `th:field`.  I can't be sure without know what conferenceTimetableMap contains, but something like this might work:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{conferenceTimetableMap[__${event.key}__].eventDescription}" />
```